# Enigmail stopped working: KEYEXPIRED/SIGEXPIRED

Tags: email, encryption, thunderbird, pgp, enigmail

Since a recent update I cant send encrypted mail with thunderbird and the enigmail plugin anymore. Whenever I try to send the mail, and enter the passphrase for my key, I get the following error message by my mail client:

```
Send operation aborted.

USERID_HINT A22[...]00 [...] <[...]@[...].org>
NEED_PASSPHRASE A22[...]00 A22[...]00 1 0
GOOD_PASSPHRASE
KEYEXPIRED 1405609045
SIGEXPIRED
KEYEXPIRED 1405609382
SIGEXPIRED
KEYEXPIRED 1405609045
SIGEXPIRED
KEYEXPIRED 1405609045
SIGEXPIRED
INV_RECP 0 0xB4[...]9A
```

What does that mean and why can't I send mails encrypted anymore?

I already checked all my keys, both the senders and the recievers keys are valid through 2019.

```
gpg -k | grep 16[...]00
pub   4096R/0x16[...]00 2014-06-13 [expires: 2019-06-12]
gpg -k | grep A3[...]86
pub   2048R/0xA3[...]86 2014-06-12 [expires: 2019-06-11]
```

I also checked my system clock and everything is allright.

I also did a `gpg --refresh-keys` on the command line. Not sure what else I could try.

Versions:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.26
libgcrypt 1.6.1
thunderbird 31.0
enigmail 1.7
```

Any idea?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Please re-read my question, I already checked that both keys expire 2019.

Comment: Is your _system_ date set to 2014?

Comment: Do not only verify the system date is in 2014, but also _after_ June 13th, I'm not sure wether the same error is given for a key not valid yet. Second thing to verify: are the signing/encryption subkeys still valid? The error message you presented somewhat indicates GnuPG is trying all signing subkeys (or the other's encryption subkeys), but not finding a valid one, those timestamps are all from mid July this year.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are also encrypting to another user-id that is encrypted on your keyring? I got bitten by this and had a long debug session until I found I still had the

```
encrypt-to
```

setting in ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf pointing at a key that had expired. Look for that key starting with 0xB4